# Android: Building for release and signing? Very unclear docs by Google

Tags: android, android-build

I am not sure if my app is correctly built for release and signed properly.

Does it have to be exported unsigned and then signed manually?

Can I export signed and then it will be signed after I choose location?

Normally I think Android docs are excellent but I find the documentation for this very important part to be frustratingly vague.

There should just be a setting in the manifest that decides what kind of build it is.
Does exporting the application make it build for release?
How can I check after signing it that it really is signed correctly?

How do I check that the jarsigner and keytool really is installed? Where are they located on Windows 7?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the documentation for signing a release version of your app is out of date. With Eclipse and the new Android Studio, all you need to do is export the signed app from the IDE.

Comment: You mean export & sign? Does an export create an app in release mode (no matter if you sign or not)?

Comment: @user3591115 Yes, and kind of. The primary difference between "debug" and "release" is how you sign the APK. All APKs must be signed in order to install them. A "debug" APK is signed with a "debug certificate". A release APK is signed with your own certificate instead.